# setInterval и clearInterval внутри функции без глобальных переменных

Tags: javascript

В примере, при нажатии на *кнопку_2*, код на базе setInterval запускает смену цвета дива. Если нажимать поочередно : *кнопка_2, затем кнопка_3*, то, похоже, запускает и
останавливает смену цвета без проблем. Если нажимать хаотично, - не работает ...
Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии *кнопки_3* всегда останавливалось на сером цвете (#ccc) и
поправить косяк, при хаотичном нажатии?

```js
function fn(x) {

  var flag = false;

  var set = setInterval(function() {
    var color = flag ? 'red' : '#ccc';
    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.background = color;
    flag = !flag;
    n += 1;
  }, 700);

  //
  if (x !== 'start') {
    clearInterval(set - 1);
    clearInterval(set);
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
</br>
<input type="button" value="1: _()." style="width:100px; height:28px; font-size:12px" onclick="fn();">
</br>
<input type="button" value="2: _('start')." style="width:100px; height:28px; font-size:12px" onclick="fn('start');">
</br>
<input type="button" value="3: _('stop')." style="width:100px; height:28px; font-size:12px" onclick="fn('stop');">
</br>

<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

upd : чтобы останавливалось на сером цвете, поместил clearInterval выше :

```
var set = setInterval(function () {
if (x !=='start') {
    clearInterval(set-1);
    clearInterval(set);
}
...
```

Comment: clearInterval(set - 1); ???

Comment: @Igor, вот такие фантазии, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fn(x) {

  var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');

  if (x !== 'start') {
    clearInterval(div.timer);
    div.timer = null;
    div.flag = false;
    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.background = '#ccc';
  } else {
    if (!div.timer) {
      div.timer = setInterval(function() {
        var div1 = document.getElementById('mydiv');
        div1.flag = !div1.flag;
        div1.style.background = div1.flag ? 'red' : '#ccc';
      }, 700);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вы мне помогли.

Comment: @Alex пожалуйста, не пишите комментарии в виде "спасибо". Когда у Вас будет достаточно [привилегий](//ru.stackoverflow.com/privileges), Вы сможете голосовать за понравившийся Вам вопрос, что на сайте Stack Overflow на русском является способом сказать спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, не такой точный, как показали выше, но всё-же :

```
function fn(x){

   var flag = false, set = setInterval(function () {

   if (x !=='start') {
      for(var i=1; i<=set; i++) clearInterval(i);
   }
   var color = flag ? 'red' : '#ccc';
   document.getElementById('mydiv').style.background = color;
   flag = !flag;
   }, 700);
}
```